# Canonical dilation vector field on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, vector-bundles, vector-fields

I am reading a paper by Langerock, called "A connection theoretic approach to sub-Riemannian geometry".

He writes:

> [Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle] ... Let $\{\phi_t\}$ represent the flow of the canonical dilation vector field on $E$ i.e. in natural vector bundle cooordinates $(x^i,y^A)$ on $E$ we have $$\phi_t(x^i,y^A)=(x^i,e^ty^A)$$

Now, I searched online but I cannot figure out what a canonical dilation vector field on a vector bundle is. Moreover, I cannot figure out what $e^t$ is in the above notation.
My best guess is  that $\phi_t:E\rightarrow E$ maps a point $e=(x^i,y^A)$ to the point obtained letting $e$ act $t$ times on itself (through the action of a vector field on itself, i.e. the one of an abelian group on itself). So we get a vertical action on each fiber when at each $t$ each point $f$ in a generic fiber is sent to $(t+1)f$ in the same fiber.

Am I correct?

Thank in advance

Comment: $e$ is just the exponential map, and $e^t$ is a number. Recall $E$ is a vector bundle so you can multiply by scalars.

Comment: @DIdier_  thought of it as a first guess, the fact he next writes the following equation, to say that $h:\pi^*N\rightarrow TE$ is a map defining a linear "$\rho$-connection" on $E$: $(\phi_t)_t(h(e,n))=h(\phi_t(e),n)$. But I guess is only unfortunate notation then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *dilation vector field* is also called the *canonical vector field* or (in the case that $E = TM$) the *Liouville vector field*.

The situation is that for every vector bundle $p: E \to B$ there is a canonical vector field $C$ on $E$ coming from the linear structure of the fibers of $E$. If we put local coordinates $(x_i, v_i)$ on $E$, then the local formula for $C$ is
$$
C_{(x_i, v_i)} = v_i \frac{\partial}{\partial v_i}\!{\LARGE\rvert}_{\normalsize\!(x_i,v_i)}.
$$
Put another way, given $v \in E$ each $C_v$ is a tangent vector in $T_v E$, which is represented by curve $\gamma(t) = v + t v$ in $E$ (i.e. $C_v = \frac{d}{dt}{\large\rvert}_{t = 0}\!\ \gamma(t)$).

It's not too difficult to see that the integral curves of this vector field are given by the global flow $\phi_t : \mathbb{R} \times E \to E$ defined by $\phi_t(v) = e^t v$, so this explains your original question. (Note that the curves $\gamma(t) = v + t v$ and $\delta(t) = e^t v$ represent the same tangent vector based at $v$ since the functions $1 + t$ and $e^t$ agree to first order at $t = 0$.)

Finally, let me give the usual global formula for $C$. Every vector bundle has a canonical *vertical lift* map $\operatorname{vlift} : E \times_B E \to TE$, a morphism of vector bundles over $E$ (we view $E \times_B E$ as a vector bundle over $E$ by the projection $\operatorname{pr}_1$ onto the first factor). It is essentially defined the same way I defined $\gamma(t)$ above (see the definition of the map "$\operatorname{vl}$" in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4870702/88896)). Given this, the vector field $C$ is defined by
$$
C_v := \operatorname{vlift}_v v.
$$
It's also worth pointing out (as manifest from any of these definitions) that each tangent vector $C_v$ is a *vertical* tangent vector, in the sense that $Dp (C_v) = 0$ (with $Dp$ the derivative of the structure map $p : E \to B$), so that $C_v$ lives entirely in the so-called *vertical subbundle*
$$
\ker Dp = VE \subset TE.
$$
In this language, the map $\operatorname{vlift}$ then defines an isomorphism of vector bundles $E \times_M E \cong VE$.